# How to start camera from fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need a camera function in my CameraFragment.java file. I already have the code for the camera and it is working in a empty application (when I put it in my MainActivity), but I don't know where to put the code in my CameraFragment.java.

I am really a beginner with Android Studio, but I couldn't find the answer on the internet. Also new on Stack Overflow.

CameraFragment.java

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment{

public static final String EXTRA_INFO = "default";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
}
}
```

AND I NEED THIS CODE IN MY CameraFragment FILE:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnCapture;
private ImageView imgCapture;
private static final int Image_Capture_Code = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_camera);
    btnCapture =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicture);
    imgCapture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capturedImage);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cInt = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cInt,Image_Capture_Code);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) {
    if (requestCode == Image_Capture_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgCapture.setImageBitmap(bp);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In fragment use same as activity but make method public 
**try this code**

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView chatRecylerview;
View view;
ChatUserlistAdapter userlistAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager manager;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userDetail = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> data;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

    btnCapture =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicture);
    imgCapture = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.capturedImage);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cInt = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cInt,Image_Capture_Code);
        }
    });
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Image_Capture_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgCapture.setImageBitmap(bp);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It works, thankyou very much!! I only had a small 'error' with my Toast.             
Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                       Can't resolve method "maketext". Do you know what I can do ?

Comment: yes sure, try this code ** Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**

Comment: You are the hero of the day! Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let me know how this works for you. Comment if you need more help setting this up.

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String EXTRA_INFO = "default";
private Button btnCapture;
private ImageView imgCapture;
private static final int Image_Capture_Code = 1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
    btnCapture =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicture);
    imgCapture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.capturedImage);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cInt = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cInt,Image_Capture_Code);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Image_Capture_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgCapture.setImageBitmap(bp);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: It's working, only had to change protected void to public void. Thankyou! Only had a small 'error' with the toast (see comments below), do you know what I can do?

Comment: Oh I see now! I updated my answer, let me know if you have more issues, I'd love to help.